# Converting illumination to irradiance

Tags: optics, units, light-emitting-diodes, intensity, photometry

I need get intensity of an LED light source, but I cannot convert lux to $W/M^2$

How does one convert illumination to irradiance? And what is the irradiance formula?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux contains a conversion table. Please at least show some effort when you post a question.

Comment: Illumination is weighted according to the sensitivity of the human eye. In order to convert to irradiance, you need to know the spectrum of the light.

Comment: @Gregory25 Did you bother noticing that, because illumination is a [photometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometry_(optics)) (as opposed to a [radiometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiometry)) quantity, irradiance is *not* in the conversion table you linked to?

Comment: @Gregory25   I don't see a table or anything else that pertains to this question on the site you linked.

Comment: I'm reminded of the fact that the responsivity of photomultiplier tubes is often specified in amps per lumen.   Practically useless.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, illuminance is a [photometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometry_(optics)) quantity, not a [radiometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiometry) one. As such, you need to know the spectrum of your light source and weigh it against the standard [luminosity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function) to get a value for the source's irradiance.

Different wavelengths have different conversion factors, because the human eye perceives brightness differently on different bands: a light source in the green will be seen as brighter than a source of the same irradiance that's off the deep end of the red where the visible starts giving way to the (invisible) infrared). Illuminance measures perceived brightness, so you need to account for this when you convert to physical energy fluxes.

Comment: Let's put some numbers on this answer.  A *lumen* is defined by 1/683 watts of green light at 555 nm, and a *lux* as one lumen per square meter.

Comment: @BertBarrois Perhaps the answer wasn't clear? **You cannot put numbers in** because the question does not specify the wavelength(s) of the light source. A lumen might be produced by 1/683 W/cm$^2$ of green light, but it will require a different intensity at other colours. Any pretense that you *can* put in numbers is misleading and a disservice to the original poster.

Comment: No need for snarkiness.  As we say in Noo Joisey, "Hey, be nice.  Ya gotta pwroblem widdat?"  For the photopic response curve, see <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function>.

Comment: As I said, any pretense that you can put in numbers without knowing the spectrum is misleading and a disservice to the OP as well as future visitors. Call me picky if you want, but I tend to have a problem with posts on this site that propagate misconceptions and create more work for other people, particularly when they're posted immediately under a correct version that I've provided, thereby diminishing the page's clarity. But hey, maybe it's just me.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the link, I wasn't sure whether it was obvious enough when I included it in the answer.